# using terra::ifel in a function

Tags: r, geospatial, terra

I'm new to terra and have to cycle a large number of `rast` objects through a byzantine set of nested conditionals. I've written it all out using `ifel` but unsure how to make a function that I can use `lapp` with.

```
r <- c(rast(matrix(1:25, nrow=5, ncol=5)),
       rast(matrix(11:35, nrow=5, ncol=5)))
names(r)[2] <- "lyr.2"

r2 <- ifel(r["lyr.1"] > 20,100,
           ifel(r["lyr.1"] <=5 & r["lyr.2"]>10, 200,
                ifel(r["lyr.2"] <= 10 & r["lyr.1"] > 5, 300,
                     9999)))
plot(r2)
```

Assuming that `r` will be a raster with consistently named layers, how can I make `r2` using a function and `lapp`?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make a function like this

```
f <- function(x) {
    ifel(x["lyr.1"] > 20,100,
     ifel(x["lyr.1"] <=5 & x["lyr.2"]>10, 200,
      ifel(x["lyr.2"] <= 10, 300, 9999)))
}

r2 <- f(r)
```

And if you have a list or SpatRasterDataset you can use it with `lapply`.

```
x <- list(r,r) 
# or
# x <- sds(r, r)
y <- lapply(x, f)
```

If you want to use `lapp` you can rewrite the function like this

```
ff <- function(x, y) {
    ifelse(x > 20, 100,
     ifelse(x <=5 & y > 10, 200,
      ifelse(y <= 10, 300, 9999)))
}
```

and do

```
x <- sds(r, r)
z <- lapp(x, ff)
```

Comment: Ah. Ok. Thanks. I'm not sure where I went wrong in writing my original function. Somehow I didn't think `ifel` would behave that way in a function call. But, of course it does. Thanks.